# Maintaining a variable when resuming an Activity in android

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a list application where it gets information from the database based on a row ID. On this page there is also an add transaction button which when clicked loads a new activity.

This activity uses the NavUtils class to go back up to the list if the user hits the home button on the top navigation but when it returns my variable hasn't been saved. Is it possible for me to keep this variable intact between the two screens or even pass it back with NatUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask()?

```
    public class DisplayAccountActivity extends Activity {

    private long account_id;       

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_account);
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            setupActionBar();

            // Receive the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            account_id = intent.getLongExtra(MainActivity.ACCOUNT_ID, 0);
    }

    public void addTransaction (View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTransactionActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            System.out.println("On resume the ID is: "+this.account_id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {             
            super.onPause();
            System.out.println("On pause the ID is: "+this.account_id);
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable static. Then you can reset it whenever you need to reset it, such as in onCreate if that's what you want.

Comment: Just gave that a try, still says "On resume the ID is: 0". Does visibility matter?

Comment: must be public if your accessing outside the class

Comment: Accessing it isn't the problem. It just still needs to be the same value when the activity is resumed.

Comment: That should work. This is the whole point of static variables. Plus I tested it. So you must be reseting it some where.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intents to pass data between activties.

In your first Activity:

```
Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondActivity");
// Package name and activity
// Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.Class);
// Explicit intents
i.putExtra("key",mystring);
// Parameter 1 is the key
// Parameter 2 is your value
startActiivty(i);
```

In your second Activity retrieve it:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("key");
//get the value based on the key
}
```

Edit:

if you want values to persist use shared preferences

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: This is just a single integer to show which account a user was viewing before they opened the add transaction screen. Is this really the only way to store the data? Seems a bit wasteful

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. here are the other options